# how to run xampp laravel code in visual studio 2022

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Can anyone help me how can i run php Laravel xampp through create code in visual studio 2022.

i tried but it's showing me error like this.

[image: Error if i run php existing code in visual studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to in your project public folder and copy the index.php after that you need to paste this on your project root folder .

edit your index.php which have been in root folder.

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
replce to **require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';**

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';
replce to **$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';**

[image: paste index.php in root folder]

and after that project will be worked in visual studio 2022.